# Can I get simple type parameter from Route attribute and complex type from uri in HttpGet?

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I'll try to explain my question in example below

if we have url such as this one:

> localhost/api/person/5?FirstName=Adam&LastName=Smith&City=London

and try to get parameters

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("person/{someId}")]
public ActionResult Location(string someId, PersonRequest request)
```

Is it possible to try something like "someId" going to by binded to "/5" and everything after "?" is binded to PersonRequest?

```
public class PersonRequest
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
}
```

I've been trying to match it with [FromUri] etc. but I don't have clue how to do this. It only works if I list down all parameters in the Location method.

Comment: Another method is creating a  [Type Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)and providing a string conversion. Then it try to bind  parameters from the URI .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FromQuery` Inline Attribute as per below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("person/{someId}")]
public ActionResult Location(string someId,[FromQuery] PersonRequest request)
{
    // TODO
}
```

By the way, I believe a good practice is to only bind search terms, filters, etc. from the query string. If your use-case is to publish a rest API then binding from the body is the correct approach.

Consider checking [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) as it may help you to acknowledge deeper regarding the bindings.

Comment: "If your use-case is to publish a rest API then binding from the body is the correct approach." But with HttpGet you can't have body :)

Comment: @Krystian Absolutely, you have to use [HttpPost] for that. I didn't change your original code as if there is a reason to which.